# Gridview DataKeyName

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I used this code to retrieve each row DataKey :

```
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
    {
        string id = gv.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

        Response.Write(id );
    }
```

But where are Gridview DataKeyNames in client code?

Comment: You are probably looking for, http://codedisplay.com/jquery-to-get-read-datakeynames-value-of-gridview-selected-rows-in-asp-net-c-vb-net/

Comment: @Adil I want to know where are DataKeyNames when I use `DataKeyNames="Id"` in my gridview . in viewstate or JS code or ... ?

Comment: You need to look at the the generated html in the browser, e.g if you left click mouse button to open context menu in chrome and click view page source

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GridView's `DataKeys` are not rendered to the client side the way ViewState is rendered to client side in a hidden field and neither the way any Asp.Net scripts are added to the page by `WebResource.axd` etc..

You need to add those key values yourself. Why not try encrypting and adding the DataKeys separately to a hidden field in your markup, in case if that's your requirement ( just an example ). OR you can simply add the `DataKeys` to ViewState too.